Why does this code result in a "Cannot store into ->" error message?
Executing this code in Pharo results in a Cannot store into -> error message?
[ :x |
x := x + 33.
x + 2] value: 5 

Is this a logical consequence of Smalltalk's syntax, or is it a consequence of the Smalltalk's semantics and their execution?

The variable x is a parameter to the block. What you see is a kind of safety measure to avoid unexpected behavior of the program to the progammer. It is something dependent on the dialect (some prohibit assignment to arguments, others warn, others do nothing).
Assignment to an argument is seen as a code smell, and that's the reason why it is prohibited.
From a VM/compiler perspective, it isn't hard to support assignment to arguments, your code is perfectly valid, and actually it takes some extra coding effort to prohibit it.

Note that you could achieve (what I consider to be) the intended behavior of your code introducing a local variable in the block:
[ :x | | y |
  y := x + 33.
  y + 2] value: 5

Note, by the way, that blocks answer with the value of it's last statement (in execution order).

I've already tried something like this successfully. The only difference I didn't declare the | y |. Would that cause it to persist outside the block?

No, it wouldn't. The scope of y is the block. Note however, that you can define y outside the block (outer scope) and freely use it inside. Just move the declaration | y | before the block. You will be able to use y both before and after the block.

Reassignment of an argument has been intentionally blocked. It's uncertain what this code intends to achieve and so it doesn't execute.

If you're trying to make a new (temporary) integer, then declare a temporary variable inside the block.
If you're trying to change the argument in place, then you can call mutating methods on it (eg +=)  (but be aware this will have repercussions outside of the block when you invoke it with mutable arguments)


"Is this a logical consequence of Smalltalk's syntax, or is it a consequence of Smalltalk's semantics and their execution?"
It is a consequnce of semantics--all parameters are passed with "In" (a.k.a. read-only) semantics.  This applies to blocks and methods alike. Allowing "In Out" semantics would break encapsulation of the outer context(s).
Why then allow read-write access to the variables of the outer context?
Same reason--because the outer context allows it, the inner context honors that expectation, except at the point of an explicit and manifest change, wherein the block header announces which variables are subject to its own encapsulation.  Anything not mentioned there will not be affected.
